# count numbers on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can the count start again if I scroll back up to the number? I have a counting number.  I do some more scrolling down the page, then I go up again back to it. I would like to see the count again from zero, is that possible?

```js
function count($this) {
  var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
  current = current + 1;
  $this.html(++current);
  if (current > $this.data('count')) {
    $this.html($this.data('count'));
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      count($this)
    }, 1);
  }
}

$(".stat-count").each(function() {
  $(this).data('count', parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
  $(this).html('0');
  count($(this));
});
```

```css
#counter {
  margin-bottom: 90%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="statscounts" id="counter">
  <div class="statwrap">
    <span class="stat-count ">400</span>
    <small>number 1</small>
  </div>
  <div class="statwrap">
    <span class="stat-count">105</span>
    <small>number 2</small>
  </div>
  <div class="statwrap">
    <span class="stat-count">321</span>
    <small>number 3</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use offsetTop property of element on window scroll event, i think that would be the easiest.

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Comment: i guess mahmoud has already given you the solution which works on window,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect the scroll position using jQuery. and once you get to the zero position you rerun the script that allows the counter. it is better to put your each in a function by calling it once you scroller to the zero position.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(scroll == 0)
     setTimeout(function(){reInitCount();},500);
});

function reInitCount(){
  $(".stat-count").each(function() {
    $(this).html('0');
    count($(this));
  });
}
```

```js
function reInitCount(){
  $(".stat-count").each(function() {
    $(this).html('0');
    count($(this));
  });
}

function count($this) {
  var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
  current = current + 1;
  $this.html(++current);
  if (current > $this.data('count')) {
    $this.html($this.data('count'));
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      count($this)
    }, 1);
  }
}

reInitCount();


$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if(scroll == 0)
         setTimeout(function(){reInitCount();},500);
      
         
});
```

```css
#counter {
  margin-bottom: 90%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="statscounts" id="counter">
  <div class="statwrap">
    <!-- it's better to initialize your data-count on the HTML side -->
    <span class="stat-count" data-count="400">0</span>
    <small>number 1</small>
  </div>
  <div class="statwrap">
    <span class="stat-count" data-count="105">0</span>
    <small>number 2</small>
  </div>
  <div class="statwrap">
    <span class="stat-count" data-count="321">0</span>
    <small>number 3</small>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   ......<br />
   
</p>
```

Comment: i mean every time that i scroll to numbers , i want to count them again . but it dosen't happen

Comment: welcome, can you mark the answer as correct plz to help others who have the same problem as you